# How to use File.Copy C# method to copy files over LAN?

Tags: c#, winforms, lan

I want to make a WinForms Application that can copy files over a LAN. Using File.Copy seems a straightforward way to do this. The example given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) shows how to copy a file to a different directory on the same computer. How can I use File.Copy to copy files from one computer to another which belongs to the same LAN?

Answer (score 4):

you can try

```
   File.Copy(@"\\server\sourceFileFolder\file1", @"\\server2\destinationFileFolder\file1");
```

also make sure to use UNC path.. here are some references.
 - [Link](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/256338-copying-file-network-share)
 - [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1158404.aspx/1)
 - [Link](http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/c-remote-file-copy-126665.html)

Comment: How can I put user name and password to server2 when I copy file to server2?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
File.Copy(
    "C:\path\yourfile.txt", 
    "\\remote_hostname\path\destinationfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`File.Copy(@"\\server\folder$\test.txt", "test.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

```
   ' code in Vb , convert it into C#       
    Dim findDirectory = "D:\UOLQserver\Data\Sound\" 
    Dim Y_N = System.IO.Directory.Exists(findDirectory)
    If Y_N = True Then
    Else
        Directory.CreateDirectory(findDirectory)
    End If
    Dim MyFilename1 = findDirectory & "\" & Today.Day & "-" & Today.Month & "-" & Today.Year & "-" & tineNow & "-" & Today.Minute & ".wav"
    FileCopy("\\SERVER\D$\UOLQserver\Data\Sound\test.wav", MyFilename1)
```